# How can I get an offline version of Stack Exchange's LaTeX input sandbox?

Tags: support, editor, latex

I really like this text editor that Stack Exchange has. It can interpret LaTeX, has a simple format, has bold, italics, quotes, click to format buttons and accepts image uploads. I'm wondering whether I can find an offline version of the Stack Exchange text/LaTeX input box that I'm using right now or whether Stack Exchange programs its own version of this sandbox or implemented some already existing LaTeX editor onto its site. In particular, is there a exe or dmg file of the Stack Exchange input sandbox that I can download?

Comment: @MarkKirby How do I use the files given in the github? I'm not a programmer and if I were I would made a dmg file or exe file of pagedown for use.

Comment: OK, that is going to be complicated and I am no dev either. Check this out https://stackedit.io/editor it has latex support and you can use it offline after loading the page once, seems strange but I did test it and it worked offline. Seems to have most fetures of the pagedown editor.

Comment: How about simply saving the page as html and using with offline? (i.e you can test with "work as offline" option in browser). I think it would work.